# Notification pop-up add link to settings window

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I've following code, this was copied from one of questions here on SOF,

```
private void showMyMessage() {
        ApplicationManager.getApplication().invokeLater(() -> {
            com.intellij.notification.Notification notification = GROUP_DISPLAY_ID_INFO
                    .createNotification("<html>TLogin failed", " Go to <a href=\"" + "LINK!!!" + "\" target=\"blank\">Settings</a> to setup login data!</html>",
                            NotificationType.ERROR,
                            new NotificationListener.UrlOpeningListener(true));
            Project[] projects = ProjectManager.getInstance().getOpenProjects();
            Notifications.Bus.notify(notification, projects[0]);
        });
    }
```

I would like to have a link instead text **"LINK!!!"**, what can you suggest ? 
I think that I need to create action and add this action to my group **GROUP_DISPLAY_ID_INFO**, but this group is not in xml it's just in code exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If take my code above as an example, need to add right after new

```
NotificationListener.UrlOpeningListener(true))

addAction(new NotificationAction("Settings") {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed (@NotNull AnActionEvent anActionEvent,
            @NotNull Notification notification){
        DataContext dataContext = anActionEvent.getDataContext();
        Project project = PlatformDataKeys.PROJECT.getData(dataContext)
        ShowSettingsUtil.getInstance().showSettingsDialog(project,
                YOURCLASS.class);
    }
```

Where yourclass.class is a class which implements Configurable interface

And now on click on Settings you will see opened settings window (yourclass.class)

Answer (score 1):

```
private static void showMyMessage(String LINK) {       
    ApplicationManager.getApplication().invokeLater(() -> {
        Notification notification = GROUP_DISPLAY_ID_INFO
            .createNotification("<html>TLogin failed", " Go to <a href=\"" + LINK + "\" target=\"blank\">Settings</a> to setup login data!</html>",
            NotificationType.ERROR,
            new NotificationListener.UrlOpeningListener(true));
        Project[] projects = ProjectManager.getInstance().getOpenProjects();
        Notifications.Bus.notify(notification, projects[0]);
    });
}
```

Just replace the link as a parameter, and use it like  `showMyMessage("http://google.com")`

Also you don't need to config the group display id in xml, just write the id in code.

Comment: thanks for reply, but `showMyMessage("http://google.com")` this code gonna lead me to google page, what I need is to be redirected to File -> Settings -> My Plugin instead. So I'm trying to understand how idea know where it should be redirected and what I need to put instead of LINK to do so